# In-App purchase missing non-consumable option?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have found this [tutorial](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/), which looks great, except the fact, that I have only "free subscription" option listed, when I enter in iTunes Connect and hit Manage In-App Purchase in my app... :/ I cannot see neither consumable nor non=consumable options :( Basically waht I want, is to upload free app with additional content, when bought via in-app purchase, but it is non-consumable, not subsciption... anybody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup the payment contracts within iTunesConnect.

Without these contracts you can not add any In-App purchases in iTunesConnect.

Comment: thx, I solved this yesterday, but the same way as you're saying, so accept ;)

Comment: I have the same. Just signed the contracts, but its validity seems to start tomorrow. Is that why i don't see Non-consumables yet? (only free subscription appears)

Answer (score 8):

The answer above was not clear to me what exactly I had to do. I will explain the steps here:

1. Go to iTunes Connect home page (the one above `Manage Your Applications`). You should see Sales and `Trends, Contract Tax and Banking`....
2. Choose `Contracts Tax and Banking` link
3. In here You probable do not have any `Master Agreements`. I had 1 contract  as a request. I clicked the `Request` button and it moved to the `Master Agreements` section (after filling in a form). The contract was in the category `Contract in Process`. This was enough to enable the other `In-App purchase` options on the `In-App Purchase` screen.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

You both are right but you are still missing one thing, that only `Admin Legal` is allowed to do this not `Admin`. I spent few hours because `Request` button was missing when i was opening **`Contracts Tax and Banking`** link because I was added as `Technical` admin. And Request button was also missing in the `itunesconnect` account where I was added as `Admin` in my another `itunesconnect` account.

[image]